# Javascript MVC/ AJAX Framework for non-app sites

Tags: javascript, framework, angularjs, mvc

I wish for my website to be more dynamic, by making use of ajax. Note that my website is a static site (with CMS) and NOT a web app.

**Requirements**

I want a JS framework such that:

- When going to different pages:

  - There is no full page refresh
  - Parts of the page not loaded again (e.g. header/ footer)
- Does not affect SEO
- Popular/ Good Support/ Good Community

**What I've looked at**

I've looked at *AngularJs* which seems to be extremely good, but the issue is that it seems that it's a very heavy framework designed mainly for web apps rather than normal websites.

Does anyone recommend any other JS framework more suitable for static sites rather than web apps (or is Angular still suitable for the job)